# Jungler or Support in Twisted Threeline (3v3 map)

Tags: league-of-legends

I play a lot of 3v3 ranked (currently gold I) and I noticed that sometimes a team would have a jungler, and sometimes a support that will assist one of his teammate bot or top.

I was wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of using both strategy, and in which situation would one work best?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty situational and surprisingly it also varies by region. In EU Most people play with a supporter while in NA the top 3v3 teams usually play with a Jungler.

The good thing about having a supporter is that you have an extremely safe early game and you can chain CC quite well. The top picks for supporters are Leona, Annie and Braum. This is essentially because in 3v3 you want to focus heavily on teamfights. With these supporters you are guaranteed to have a really strong Midgame teamfights. Having a supporter can also help you surviving ganks more easily.

Jungler comps have 3 big advantages. You have 2 solo lanes and a jungler that can also keep up in levels/gold if played correctly, you can control Vilemaw more easily and your lategame is really strong. Also here  you want to focus on teamfighting abilities. Usually you want to send a bruiser with AOE abilities into the jungle.

So basically the winners in categories are:

- Safety: Support
- Levels/Gold: Jungle
- Objective Control: Jungle
- Midgame: Support
- Lategame: Jungle
- CC: Usually Support
- Damage: Usually Jungle

This means: If you are sure that you can win rather quickly you should go with support. It's also a lot safer. However if you want to take the game to 25 min or more you should probably go for a jungler.

Comment: awesome answer! exactly what i am think but better explained

Comment: +1 - This is completely accurate. Both have their ups and downs and play different ways. What you want to play is preference

Answer (score 3):

The one thing I recommend in 3v3 is to play some compositions such as one APC with a lot of control and a safe farming phase (Morgana, Graggy, Ziggs), one bruiser that can be an ADC pick or at least that can hard carry end game (or the contrary) such as Jayce, Vayne, Trynda, Trundle. And for the last role, with my teammates we figured out that something really cool is to play junglers that can be viable as support (or the contrary) in 5v5 games, such as Nunu, Nautilus, WW, Cho'Gath... Even Morgana works!

And so, with this kind of compo, you can take a smite, support your ADC/bruiser and everytime you can, you go in the jgl to take some farm, or go and gank the other lane while your ADC/bruiser plays safe.

Using this technique made us climb to Plat IV in 3v3 last season, and it is also working this season (Gold II last week)

Comment: This seems like a good strategy. But you speak about supporting an "ADC/Bruiser", would you take someone strong early but bad in late like Pantheon, Lee sin? Or would you favor ADC/bruiser like Jax, Yasuo, Riven, Fiora, ... (better late)?

Comment: It depends on your other champions :) We usually did Trynda/morgana/nunu, so something quite end game, but if you avoid trades early using your CC, then late game is nice. You can also want to stomp with an ultra early composition, but i think it's more risky. You should find a good balance between early and end game in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

Having a Jungler has 4 pros:

1. You dont need to split the XP on the lanes.
2. There is gold in the creeps which would be unused
3. you can gank easier
4. you have better altair control

Having a Support has only the advantage, that you may feed your ADC or APC easier.

If you have a Jungler on your team, and the enemies play with a Support you will have one player on your team, that has to play against 2 champs, which can be pretty tough.

Comment: Advantage of support is that you can sometimes zone out the other laner from gold/exp too.